# Problems with passing callback from controller to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to pass a function from a controller to a directive so an event fired from the directive could cause a refresh in a different controller.

```
controllers.controller('UserCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.name="Name";
  $scope.test = function (t) {
    console.log("Inside "+t+" "+$scope.name)
    return $scope.test2();
  };
  $scope.test2 = function(){
    return 2;
  }
}

<my-test-directive respond="test">
```

This seems to work fine but when I change it to try and match the [Google Angular conventions](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/angularjs-google-style.html#directives) I get an undefined error on return `this.test2();`. Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VbHHNaDdcJNYdsq6L1R1?p=preview) with the failing version.

Using the "Google Angular style" how would I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Mugs2C7UOjlXx1L3LsMP?p=preview

You need to change few things :

1. To call function from directive you should use '&' instead '='
2. In your html change `respond="userController.test"` to `respond="userController.test(msg)"`
3. Finally you should pass object to function instad of string change  `scope.respond("So I should be getting inside");` to `scope.respond({msg:"So I should be getting inside"})`

I hope that will helps.

Comment: Will this work with IE8 then that is an actual concern of mine

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a function in javascript the context of the function gets lost so the `this` keyboard won't work anymore. If you want to pass your test function you need to wrap it in a function that is bound to userCtrl. You can do this with `bind()` by adding the following line to your controller's constructor and passing `boundTest` to your directive instead of `test`

```
this.boundTest = this.test.bind(this);
```

Note that `bind()` was introduced in ES5 so it won't work in IE8

Here is a working plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/BTuwTFf2XsmrR3As4x1x?p=preview

Comment: I get where you are coming from and I think you are right. I however, came up with what I think is a slightly cleaner answer. Going to leave it up and let the community upvote the more accurate answer because honestly I am not sure :-)

Comment: Actually on second thought I do like yours better! Thanks!

Comment: haha yeah it is a bit of a hack and I wish Angular/javascript handled this situation better. I think sss's answer would be the one officially recommended by Angular but I just hate the syntax for '&' attributes. You just gotta pick the lesser of 3 evils ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is [what I came up with](http://plnkr.co/edit/ymiDogV3EKFzaJEPPTUX?p=preview)

Thanks to rob for the idea, I don't know that I like this though for two reasons...

1.) I cannot seem to use prototype, limiting my inheritance options (as I understand it)
2.) This looks rather hacky

```
$scope.userController.test2();
```

Depending on the vote count and comments will depend what I mark as the answer so please provide feedback